# Find all phrases that contain at least one word from a list file and save them to new files

Tags: python, linux

I have 2 files:
- phrases.txt
- words_to_erase.txt

I need a way to find all the phrases from 'phrases.txt' that contain at least 1 word from the 'words_to_replace.txt' file and create the following:

new_phrases.txt: this is the new file without all the phrases found on the previous step.

erased_phrases: this file contains all the phrases that were erased to create the 'new_phrases.txt' file

I can either use python or linux for this.

Note:

phrases.txt is a file that contains 100k phrases, 1 phrase per line

words_to_erase.txt is a file that contains 80 different words, 1 word per line.

I tried using Linux:

```
grep -f words_to_erase.txt phrases.txt > newfile.txt
```

this way I only get a file with the new phrases without the replaced phrases, I don't think this case insensitive though, I tried using -i with it and it doesn't seem to work.

I tried python with something like:

```
in_file = open("words_to_erase.txt", "rt") 
contents = in_file.read(line)         
in_file.close()     
print contents              

sourcefile = "phrases.txt"
filename2 = "newfile.txt"

def fixup( filename ): 
    print "fixup ", filename 
    fin = open( filename ) 
    fout = open( filename2 , "w") 
    for line in contents: 
        if not any(item in line for item in contents):
                fout.write(line)  
    fin.close() 
    fout.close() 

fixup(sourcefile)
```

Comment: 1) Homework-like problems should show effort. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Stackoverflow is not a homework-solving service.
2) Python is a coding language, linux is a operating system...what do you mean you can use either?

Comment: added what I have so far

Comment: You might want to consider what the `-v` option does to `grep` in `grep -v -f words_to_replace.txt phrases.txt`.

Comment: @DanD. something is missing because the words_to_erase.txt file has 80 different words I want to look for and the result of the # of erased lines I get is 299, but when I grep only a single word from the words_to_erase.txt like this `grep -v -f 'the' phrases.txt` the result of the lines erased is 1546 lines so the grep from the words_to_erase.txt file results on less lines than doing it word by word, that;'s where i'm stuck at. Thanks

Comment: @enumaris I realize linux and python are totally different, I'm familiar and learning both Linux and python and I know what I'm looking to do at the moment can be tackled with either one, python would be more interesting since it could be more scalable but both work. Sorry for not adding a complete question at first but whatever I added now is what I have so far, Thanks.

Comment: @DanD added the solution to my original comment thanks for your help

Comment: @enumaris added the solution to my original comment thanks for your help

Comment: @Alex :If you got your answer, then you might want to post the answer in the answer section and mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this script to grep from a file that contained 400k phrases(phrases.txt) and erase all lines that contained a word from a file that contained 1,000 words(words_to_erase.txt), the script took about 15 minutes to finish but with 100% accuracy.

Note.- When I was using grep -f words_to_erase.txt phrases.txt, grep was skipping many phrases that included words from words_to_erase.txt file, with this bash script it searches word by word and it outputs the correct number of phrases.

1. To create the script:
   Copy this script and paste it on a text editor, save it with any name and extension .sh

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cat words_to_erase.txt | while read line 
   do
       echo $line
       grep -iwv $line phrases.txt >> newfile.txt
       cat newfile.txt | sort | uniq >> final_file.txt
   done
   ```

2.- Make the script excecutable:

```
    chmod -x $name_of_script.sh
```

3. Run the script:

   ```
   ./$name_of_script.sh
   ```